# Karma coverage thresholds

Tags: code-coverage, karma-runner, jscoverage

I am currently using Karma's coverage within a project, I would like to enforce a threshold for the coverage to be set at and therefore make my builds on Circle CI to fail and go red due to it being lower than a set percentage.

Comment: You should really accept the answer you've got at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: yeah apologise I hadn't seen the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install [`karma-threshold-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-threshold-reporter) and configure it as shown in the README.

Comment: A short eight and a half years later , the [repo](https://github.com/lithiumtech/karma-threshold-reporter) and [site](https://github.com/lithiumtech/karma-threshold-reporter) are kaput.  Any other good options? ([This](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#check) might be useful.)

Comment: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#check was posted three years ago, but deleted because it was only a link -_-.  I guess it's a problem of the question, but nevertheless I don't see better ways to ask or answer, and since web search is increasingly broken nowadays (enshittification) …